# How to read all content of Epub file in android?

Tags: java, android, epub

I want to read all content of all toc. 
Can u please tell me how to read all chapter which is there in table of content(toc ).
Please post modified code so that we can read all content or post some thing so that i can read content .

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
       AssetManager assetsmanger=getAssets();

        try {                                   
             // find InputStream for book                   
                InputStream  epubInputStream=assetsmanger.open("books/INCOME-TAX-ACT-1961.epub");

              // Load Book from inputStream
              Book book = (new EpubReader()).readEpub(epubInputStream);

            // Log the book's authors                         
              Log.i("epublib", "author(s): " +book.getMetadata().getAuthors());

                // Log the book's title  
             Log.i("epublib", "title: " + book.getTitle());

        String data=new String (book.getContents().get(3).getData()); 
         String k=data;
                web1=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);    
//                txt1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
//                txt1.setText(k);
            web1.loadData(k," text/html", "utf8");

        Bitmap coverImage=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(book.getCoverImage().getInputStream());

         Log.i("epublib" , "Coverimage is " + coverImage.getWidth() + " by "
                  + coverImage.getHeight() + " pixels");
        // Log the tale of contents
         logTableOfContents(book.getTableOfContents().getTocReferences(), 0);

    //     list=(ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);


//      img1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);    
//            img1.setImageBitmap(coverImage);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 Log.e("epublib", e.getMessage());
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    private void logTableOfContents(List<TOCReference> tocReferences, int depth) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(tocReferences== null ){
            return;
        }
        for(TOCReference tocReference:tocReferences){
            StringBuilder tocstring=new StringBuilder();
            for(int i=0;i<depth;i++)
            {
                tocstring.append("\t");

            }
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();


        String k=   tocstring.append(tocReference.getTitle()).toString();
        map.put("TOC",k);
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list1 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        list1.add(map);
        String t=k;
             Log.i("epublib", tocstring.toString());
             logTableOfContents(tocReference.getChildren(), depth + 1);

        }           
    }                                     
    }
```

Comment: what output are you getting with this code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how read all content according to Chapter wise in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895224/how-read-all-content-according-to-chapter-wise-in-android)

Comment: i want to read all chapter one by one ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this code provided you have necessary libraries and `sampleepubfile.epub` in your `assets`...

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.List;

import nl.siegmann.epublib.domain.Book;
import nl.siegmann.epublib.domain.TOCReference;
import nl.siegmann.epublib.epub.EpubReader;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebView;
public class EPubDemo extends Activity {
    WebView webview;
    String line, line1 = "", finalstr = "";
    int i = 0;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        try {
            // find InputStream for book
            InputStream epubInputStream = assetManager
                    .open("sampleepubfile.epub");

            // Load Book from inputStream
            Book book = (new EpubReader()).readEpub(epubInputStream);

            // Log the book's authors
            Log.i("author", " : " + book.getMetadata().getAuthors());

            // Log the book's title
            Log.i("title", " : " + book.getTitle());

            /* Log the book's coverimage property */
            // Bitmap coverImage =
            // BitmapFactory.decodeStream(book.getCoverImage()
            // .getInputStream());
            // Log.i("epublib", "Coverimage is " + coverImage.getWidth() +
            // " by "
            // + coverImage.getHeight() + " pixels");

            // Log the tale of contents
            logTableOfContents(book.getTableOfContents().getTocReferences(), 0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("epublib exception", e.getMessage());
        }

        String javascrips = "";
        try {
            // InputStream input = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.lights);
            InputStream input = this.getAssets().open(
                    "poe-fall-of-the-house-of-usher.epub");

            int size;
            size = input.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            input.read(buffer);
            input.close();
            // byte buffer into a string
            javascrips = new String(buffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // String html = readFile(is);

        webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", javascrips,
                "application/epub+zip", "UTF-8", null);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void logTableOfContents(List<TOCReference> tocReferences, int depth) {
        if (tocReferences == null) {
            return;
        }

        for (TOCReference tocReference : tocReferences) {
            StringBuilder tocString = new StringBuilder();
             for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
             tocString.append("\t");
             }
             tocString.append(tocReference.getTitle());
             Log.i("TOC", tocString.toString());

            try {
                InputStream is = tocReference.getResource().getInputStream();
                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                    // line1 = Html.fromHtml(line).toString();
                    Log.v("line" + i, Html.fromHtml(line).toString());
                    // line1 = (tocString.append(Html.fromHtml(line).toString()+
                    // "\n")).toString();
                    line1 = line1.concat(Html.fromHtml(line).toString());
                }
                finalstr = finalstr.concat("\n").concat(line1);
                // Log.v("Content " + i, finalstr);
                i++;
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }

            logTableOfContents(tocReference.getChildren(), depth + 1);
        }
        webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", finalstr, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
    }
}
```

Comment: i have libaries and i m able to read static chapter from  String data=new String (book.getContents().get(3).getData()); but i want to read all content chapter wise please suggest me how to do this

Comment: i want to open online epub file so please suggest me how to do this?

Comment: please give me library download link

Comment: Hi GAMA, I found the **`Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory`** error while using above code. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try adding `slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar` to the build path.

Comment: Is it possible to make book pages horizontally scrollable? How can we extract pages from the book or spines.

Comment: @NehaDhanwani Have you found a solution?